# How to move the camera using react-three-fiber and @react-three/drei?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber, drei

I'm drawing a 3d model with the following configuration.

- [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber)
- [@react-three/drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei)

The following is a CodeSandBox with a model drawn.
[CodeSandBox-A](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-mendel-ersc7)

The drawn model is close to the top of the canvas, and I want to center it.

[image: canvas]

Could you please tell me how to center the model on the canvas?
This is the first time I've touched Three.js, so I'm sure I may have made some elementary mistakes.

---

The code is as follows.
I referred to the following document for the props of the Canvas component.
[React Three Fiber Documentation](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/canvas)

```js
import { useMemo, Suspense } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
const { useGLTF, OrbitControls, Stage } = require("@react-three/drei");

const CanvasContainer = () => {
  const { scene } = useGLTF("/scene.glb");
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ fov: 70, position: [0, 1000, 1000] }}>
    // No matter what I put in this "position" value, I could not see any change in the canvas.
      <OrbitControls enablePan={true} enableZoom={true} enableRotate={true} />
      <Stage>
        <group dispose={null}>
          <primitive scale={[1, 1, 1]} object={scene} />
        </group>
      </Stage>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const isWindow = typeof window === "undefined";
  const memoCanvas = useMemo(() => <CanvasContainer />, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Canvas</h1>
      <div className="canvas_container">
        {!isWindow && <Suspense fallback={<div />}>{memoCanvas}</Suspense>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

[setDefaultCamera removed in v6.x. · Issue #1147 · pmndrs/react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/1147)
I also tried the code to use `useThree` as described in the above Issue.
The following is its CodeSandBox.
[CodeSandBox-B](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-beaver-ngspl)
As you can see from the CodeSandBox, I was unable to move the camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give orbitcontrols the "makeDefault" prop, then it should in the center. otherwise check out dreis Bounds component. see: https://twitter.com/0xca0a/status/1453807293074661385

the memocanvas thing btw makes no sense, don't put jsx into usememo.